# Repository Pattern with Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I'm pretty new to the repository pattern and dependency injection. Almost all repository patterns I've come across has some sort of GetAll() method like so:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    // other CRUD methods here...
}
```

I'm having an issue implementing this interface and the GetAll() method because I am calling a stored procedure that requires a parameter that changes based on a user's input. I don't want to add an ad-hoc method to the repository interface e.g. `IQueryable<T> GetAll(string input);`. I also don't want to add a parameter to the constructor because it looks a little messy to me:

```
public class ConcreteRepository : IRepository<Entity>
{
    string _storedProcedureInput;

    public ConcreteRepository(string storedProcedureInput)
    {
        _storedProcedureInput = storedProcedureInput;

    public IQueryable<Entity> GetAll()
    {
        // Call to stored procedure goes here passing in the 
        // _storedProcedureInput variable.
    }
}
```

I'm also using dependency injection so I would have to add some dynamic input to the constructor when binding:

```
Bind<IRepository<Entity>>().To<ConcreteRepository>().WithConstructorArgument(?)
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I'd like to reuse the IRepository interface. For example, in one program I'm using EF4 to implement the GetAll() method, and in another program I'm using standard ADO.NET to call a stored procedure like the example above.

Comment: Your code looks absolutely allright and according to repostitory pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your GetAll isn't necessarily getting all. In which case you may as well rename it or have another method which more accurately describes the functionality offered by your stored procedure which takes appropriate input parameter(s) that can be passed to the procedure.

Comment: Does that mean I need to add another method to the repository interface e.g. `IQueryable<T> StoredProcedureMethod(string input)`? When it comes time to reuse the repository interface, there is a good chance the StoredProcedureMethod() will not be implemented.

Comment: @jodev It depends on what your SP is actually doing - it sounds like it's returning a sub set of all records. You could always try and abstract out the inputs by having GetAllMatches<T>(SomeMatchingObject criteria). It's hard to comment further without knowing what the SP does.

Comment: thanks. I am returning a sub set so it does make sense that another method like you suggested should handle the call.

Comment: You don't need to add it to the generic interface; you can add it to a specific interface. Like so: IOrderRepository : IRepository<Order> { additional methods here }. Then you can use DI to make sure when someone requests an IRepository<Order> they get IOrderRepository with its additional methods. And of course, clients that need those additional methods can request it directly.

Answer (score 5):

can't you added a new method in your IRepository to execute custom stored proc:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute Stored Proc with result set returned.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="procName"></param>
    /// <returns>An object resultset</returns>
    T ExecuteCustomStoredProc<T>(string procName, SqlParameter params);
```

and in your Implementation (ConcreteRepository) you can put this logic it:

```
        public T ExecuteCustomStoredProc<T>(string commandName, SqlParameter params)
        {
            return this._repositoryContext.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>(commandName, params);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that if you are using GetAll with a stored procedure you are kind of missing the point.

The example of GetAll that returns an IQueryable infers delay execution in some form, but if you are making a call to a stored procedure the execution will not be delayed.

I'd suggest keeping the GetAll function, but as a call into your ORM's context. The calls you have to the stored procedures, keep as separate methods, but return something like `IList<Entity>`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I modified my post. I will be using the GetAll() method for stored procedures and EF4's `DbContext`.